# Concatenate parent attributes recursively

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Given the following XML:

```
<package>
    <node name="a">
        <node name="b"/>
        <node name="c"/>
        <node name="d">
            <node name="e"/>
            <node name="f"/>
            <node name="g">
                <node name="h"/>
            </node>
        </node>    
    </node>
</package>
```

I basically want to flatten the tree while concatenating the `name` attributes of each parent `node` element until the last `node` element:

```
<package>
    <node name="a-b"/>
    <node name="a-c"/>
    <node name="a-d-e"/>
    <node name="a-d-f"/>
    <node name="a-d-g-h"/>
</package>
```

What I got working so far is is properly generating a flat list of all `node` elements using a template and `xsl:copy-of`:

```
<xsl:template match="//node">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives me:

```
<package>
    <node name="b"/>
    <node name="c"/>
    <node name="e"/>
    <node name="f"/>
    <node name="h"/>
</package>
```

But I'm not sure how to properly continue from here. My intention was to extend the template and using `xsl:attribute` and `xsl:for-each` to concatenate and modify the attribute:

```
    <xsl:template match="node/@name">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::node">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">.</xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

However, this only prints the `node`'s data (if any).
What am I missing here?

I have XSLT 2.0 available and I got my inspiration from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222656/xslt-recursively-concatenate-parent-node-attribute-value-with-child-node-attrib).

Comment: Good question. There are both an XSLT 2.0 solution and an XSLT 1.0 solutions that are are short and concise.

Comment: Also, about the reason your solution doesn't produce the wanted results -- you need to know how the XSLT processing model works, this explains why the template, matching `icon/@name` was never selected for execution (applied)

Comment: Also, the specified wanted result in the question incorrectly contains this: `    <node name="a-d-f-g-h"/>` -- this shouldn't be output, because the `node`element  with attribute `name` with value `f` is not parent of the `node`element  with attribute `name` with value `g`. The correct element to output is: `   <node name="a-d-g-h"/>`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You're completely right - I have edited the question in order to fix the "typos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I basically want to flatten the tree while concatenating the name
>   attributes of each parent node element until the last node element:

**Here is a complete and working XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[*]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[not(*)]/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(../ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<package>
    <node name="a">
        <node name="b"/>
        <node name="c"/>
        <node name="d">
            <node name="e"/>
            <node name="f"/>
            <node name="g">
                <node name="h"/>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</package>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<package>
   <node name="a-b"/>
   <node name="a-c"/>
   <node name="a-d-e"/>
   <node name="a-d-f"/>
   <node name="a-d-g-h"/>
</package>
```

---

II. **XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[*]"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[not(*)]/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="gen"/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node/@name" mode="gen">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../parent::node/@name" mode="gen"/>
    <xsl:if test="../parent::node">-</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<package>
   <node name="a-b"/>
   <node name="a-c"/>
   <node name="a-d-e"/>
   <node name="a-d-f"/>
   <node name="a-d-g-h"/>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string-join`:

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <node name="{string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I managed to modify my stylesheet as per your recommendation and I managed to get it work they way I intended.
However: How would I do this using `xsl:copy-of` on the `node` element so I get all of it's data copied and them modify the attribute instead of manually outputing a new `node` element? In my real life application the `node` elements have data (eg. an author and file-path field).

Comment: Sorry, but you can't use `xsl:copy-of` as that makes a deep copy and you want to transform the node. You can of course also write a template matching the attribute instead and use e.g. `<xsl:template match="node/@name"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/></xsl:template>` and have the node elements and its other attributes or contents handled by the identity transformation template.

Comment: Or write a template for `node` and use `<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I managed to get everything working now :)
Should I update my question and leave the full stylesheet in there?

Comment: The stylesheet you have used finally? You can provide it as your own answer but make sure you edit the question with the some input and output sample better representing the requirement that `node` elements are not empty and that you need the contents to be copied as well, otherwise it will be hard to relate it to the problem described so far in the question.