# Concatenate parent attributes recursively - And preserve element data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is a follow-up on my previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328070/concatenate-parent-attributes-recursively). It turned out that I made my minimal test case too minimal.

Given the following XML:

```
<package>
    <node name="a">
        <node name="b">
            <author>John Doe</author>
            <date>2015-12-15</date>
        </node>
        <node name="c">
            <author>Franzis Cooper</author>
            <date>2014-09-08</date>
        </node>
        <node name="d">
            <node name="e">
                <author>Some dude</author>
                <date>2015-02-18</date>
            </node>
            <node name="f">
                <author>Max Planck</author>
                <date>1858-04-23</date>
            </node>
            <node name="g">
                <node name="h">
                    <author>Jane Doe</author>
                    <date>2019-07-15</date>
                </node>
            </node>    
        </node>
    </node>
</package>
```

I want to apply an XSL transformation that results in the following:

- All `node`s flattened (eg. all `node` elements are direct children of `package`.
- The `name` attribute of each `node` is concatenated to reflect the original hierarchy (see previous SO question).
- The data of the last `node` in the original tree hierarchy (the `node` that has no further `node` children) is preserved/copied.

For example, the XML input posted above should look like this after applying the transformation:

```
<package>
    <node name="a-b">
        <author>John Doe</author>
        <date>2015-12-15</date>
    </node>
    <node name="a-c">
        <author>Franzis Cooper</author>
        <date>2014-09-08</date>
    </node>
    <node name="a-d-e">
        <author>Some dude</author>
        <date>2015-02-18</date>
    </node>
    <node name="a-d-f">
        <author>Max Planck</author>
        <date>1858-04-23</date>
    </node>
    <node name="a-d-g-h">
        <author>Jane Doe</author>
        <date>2019-07-15</date>
    </node>
</package>
```

The original question helped me to flatten the tree and concatenate the `name` attributes correctly. I took that as a starting point and modified it so that the final `node`'s data is preserved:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform each node -->
    <xsl:template match="node[*]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Modify the 'name' attribute of each node that doesn't have a child -->
    <xsl:template match="node[not(*)]/@name">
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(../ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the transformation will copy the `node`'s data (eg. the `author` element) but then omit the `node` element itself.

I was assuming that I can simply call `xsl:copy-of` within the template that modifies the last `node`'s `name` attribute. However, as the XSLT processor is telling me that's not possible.

I'm extremely new to XSLT and the learning curve seems rather steep. I'd appreciate any kind of help on this.

XSLT 2.0 is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `node[*]` matches not only the `node` elements you want to remove, but also those you want to keep. Try changing:

```
<xsl:template match="node[*]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="node[*/*]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="node[node]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

In addition, I believe your last template needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="node[not(node)]/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(../ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or just:

```
<xsl:template match="@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(../ancestor-or-self::node/@name, '-')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

What you have now does not match anything in your input, because (again) **all** `node` elements have child elements.

Comment: Using the code you proposed allowed me to make this work. Thanks a lot - I understand my mistake(s) now :)