# RML Mapping with recursive traversal of nodes with parent attribute appended each time

Tags: xml, recursion, xpath, rdf, rml-rdf

I am trying to map an XML source to RDF and would like to know how to traverse recursively while keeping track of the parent's attributes each time. In the example shown, I want all `Person` nodes to be extracted with the `name` of each parent  node appended to the current node. Considering all parent names is necessary as the node names may not be unique. (See `grandChild1` two times in the example)

Note that I do not know in advance how many levels the nesting can go and hence adding one TriplesMap for each level is not a feasible option.

After having gone through the [documentation](https://rml.io/specs/rml/), [examples](https://rml.io/docs/rml/examples/), and [test cases](https://rml.io/test-cases/), I am not quite sure if this is even possible.

Following are a simplified sample XML, the RML mapping I created so far, the current RDF output generated using [RMLMapper](https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java), as well as the RDF output I am expecting.

Data

```xml
<Root>
    <Person>
        <name>parent1</name>
        <Children>
            <Person>
                <name>child1</name>
                <Person>
                    <name>grandchild1</name>
                    <Children>
                        <Person>
                            <name>greatgrandchild1</name>
                        </Person>
                    </Children>
                </Person>
            </Person>
            <Person>
                <name>child2</name>
                <Person>
                    <name>grandchild1</name>
                </Person>
            </Person>
        </Children>
    </Person>
</Root>
```

Mapping

```
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

@prefix testont: <http://www.example.com/ontology/> .
@prefix : <http://www.example.com/rules/> .
@base <http://www.example.com/instance/> .


:TriplesMapPerson a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "recursion_data.xml";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath;
        rml:iterator "//Root/Person"
    ].

:TriplesMapPerson rr:subjectMap [
    rr:template "{name}"
].

:TriplesMapPerson rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate rdf:type;
    rr:object testont:Person
].

:TriplesMapChild a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "recursion_data.xml";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath;
        rml:iterator "//Root/Person/Children/Person"
    ].

:TriplesMapChild rr:subjectMap [
    rr:template "{name}_{../../name}"
].

:TriplesMapChild rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate rdf:type;
    rr:object testont:Person
].
```

Current RDF

```
<http://www.example.com/instance/parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/child1_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/child2_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
```

Expected RDF

```
<http://www.example.com/instance/parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/child1_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/grandchild1_child1_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/greatgrandchild1_grandchild1_child1_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/child2_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
<http://www.example.com/instance/grandchild1_child2_parent1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person>.
```

I appreciate any assistance in resolving this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could recursively concatenate `name`s in XSLT.

Comment: Could you kindly point me to an example or similar? I haven't used XSLT so far and the documentation seems quite extensive.

Comment: Like this, I suppose:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57328070/7879193

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the recursive nature of XPath's `//` operator to iterate over all persons, regardless of depth.

Then, in your subject template, you can use XPath's ancestor-or-self axis to get a list of ancestors nodes that have a name, reverse it to get the desired order, and get the name attribute for each node:

```
for $ancestor in reverse(ancestor-or-self::*[name]) return $ancestor/name
```

Then you can use XPaths string-join function to join the values to get the desired result.

The mapping would then look like

```
:Person a rr:TriplesMap ;
  rml:logicalSource [
    rml:source [a carml:Stream ];
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath;
    rml:iterator "//Person"
  ] ;
    rr:subjectMap [
    rr:template "{string-join(for $ancestor in reverse(ancestor-or-self::*[name]) return $ancestor/name, '_')}" ;
    rr:class testont:Person ;
  ] ;
.
```

Giving the following result:

```
<http://example.com/base/parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .

<http://example.com/base/child1_parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .

<http://example.com/base/grandchild1_child1_parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .

<http://example.com/base/greatgrandchild1_grandchild1_child1_parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .

<http://example.com/base/child2_parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .

<http://example.com/base/grandchild1_child2_parent1> a <http://www.example.com/ontology/Person> .
```

Note that for this to work the XPath implementation of your mapping tool needs to support reverse-axis traversal. I ran this example through https://github.com/carml/carml which supports that.

Note also that your xml input example is missing some intermediary `Children` nodes for some `Person` nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does that mean getting something like this `<http://www.example.com/instance/greatgrandchild1_grandchild1_child1_parent1>` would not be possible in RML, in your view?

Comment: @swathis after thinking about this some more, I realised it could be solved with XPath's ancestor-or-self axis and string-join function. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again for the revision. I tried it with RMLMapper and seems like neither the reverse-axis traversal nor the string-join function is supported. So I will give this another try with CARML and report how it goes.